# Is there a VSCode problemMatcher for elm-make?

Tags: visual-studio-code, elm, elm-make

I would like to run elm-make as a task in VSCode and have the results show up in the PROBLEMS window. I've been able to set up a task that is working for me as follows.

```
{
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "command": "elm",
    "isShellCommand": true,
    "args": ["make", "Index.elm"],
    "showOutput": "always"
}
```

The problem however is that this dumps the text results to the OUTPUT window with no color and no support for navigating the results with [editor.action.marker.next](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/master/docs/editor/editingevolved.md). Is there an existing problemMatcher for elm-make output? If not then is there a straight forward way to specify a custom one to do the job perhaps based on a regular expression?